# Control Flow: How to get the data to show and not the index

Tags: r, for-loop

I have the code below that I'm trying to loop the condition over. I keep getting the indexes of the data frame instead of the elements (which is what I want) of the data frame.

```
airport <- airport_data
for (i in 1:135) {
    if (airport$Scheduled[i] < airport$Performed[i])
        print(i)
}

Airport          City      Scheduled  Performed
HARTSFIELD INTL  ATLANTA   280003     298003
BALTI INTL       BALTIMOR  56001      59000
```

Comment: Change `print(i)` to `print(airport[i,])`

Comment: You can also do `airport[airport$Scheduled < airport$Performed,]` and forego the for loop altogether.

Comment: @jake2389 Thanks. It produced the whole row now I'd just like to know how it will combine all the rows like below
   `Airport                        City               Scheduled  Performed
    HARTSFIELD INTL  ATLANTA       280003      298003
    WASH INTL              BALTIMORE  56244        58001`

Comment: What do you mean "combine all the rows"? Did you try my second suggestion?

Comment: I did try the first suggestion since I'm trying to learn the concept of looping and it did work. However, it's producing each row individually.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to give a definitive answer without seeing your dataframe, but the best way is to specify which column you want the loop to start is below - e.g. if you wanted the loop to start on the second column of your dataframe the code would be:

```
airport <- airport_data
for (i in 2:ncol(airport){
if (airport$Scheduled[i]<airport$Performed[i])
print(i)}
```

Comment: The data frame has the same columns as the expected output shown below the code in the question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine the rows then you shouldn't print them. I understand you're trying to practice for loops, but when you're working with matrices or data, you want to use **vectorized** operations, and not work on a row one by one.

Vectorized operations are optimized to be much faster than a typical for loop, and you should always try a vectorized solution in a language like R or Matlab.

```
airport[airport$Scheduled < airport$Performed,]
```

That being said, if you really want to do it with a for loop and want to "merge" the rows, you can just `rbind` them:

```
result <- data.frame() # empty frame
for (i in 1:135) {
    if (airport$Scheduled[i] < airport$Performed[i])
        result <- rbind(result, airport[i,])
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Okay now that I have a better idea of what you want, I actually think you're better off using filter (from library(dplyr)). Make sure both airport$scheduled and airport$Performed as in numeric form.

```
new_df <- filter(airport, airport$Scheduled < airport$Performed)
```

Comment: Learn to [edit] your answers when you better understand the question.